# Malformed or unreadable .cdg file when using EasyUML plugin netbeans

Tags: plugins, netbeans-8

I want to do a reverse engineering process using easy-UML plugin in netbeans8.1, but I get the error "Malformed or unreadable .cdg file" once I create the class diagram. In the forum of the plugin, some people comented about it, but didn't help. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the code you have used so far, and which error is throwing the error?

Comment: I didn't use code to do that, just right-clicked on the package and selected "easyuml Create Class Diagram". it's that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exception and in my case the problem was in non-latin symbols in UMLDiagrams project path.